# Typescript how to import and export

Tags: javascript, typescript, import, export

Here is the script line in html

```
<script src="a.js"></script>
```

I have also tried setting type="module"

a.ts

```
import {hello} from "./b"
console.log(hello);
```

b.ts

```
export let hello: string = "bob";
```

I have also tried a bunch of different options in my tsconfig file like changing the module to everything possible option as well as the target

Nothing is logged to console sometimes error like exports is not defined or define is not defined or sometimes no errors but nothing is shown

Please help.

Comment: how about the module: 'commonjs' in tsconfig?

Answer (score 0):

The solution seems to be pretty simple. Add .js at the end of the import line

```
import {hello} from "./b.js"
```

and it should work fine. Maybe the problem was that JS didn't know what file should be imported.